# GET method with json body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httprequest

I have to consume methods from an external API provided, and one method is a GET with a json body. I'm making the connection through rails using rest-client gem that makes that job.

I know that RestClient.post accepts json:

```
RestClient.post "http://example.com/resource", { 'x' => 1 }.to_json, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
```

And also for my case works perfectly. But if i change the .post to .get, i get this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
from /Users/toptierlabs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:67:in `get'
from /Users/toptierlabs/Desktop/Proyectos/AppraisalLane/app/models/autoniq.rb:8:in `getCircleInventory'
from (irb):3
from /Users/toptierlabs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/toptierlabs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/toptierlabs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Is there any way in Rails to do a GET with a json body? Or any possible solution to translate a "get with a json body" to something else? Is not necessary to use the rest-client gem, if any one have another solution is welcome too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

RestClient.get "http://example.com/resource", params: {'json' => { 'x' => 1 }.to_json},:content_type => :json, :accept => :json